# How to generate 4 digit random number

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is what i have tried so far but some times its returning 3 digit or 2 digit or even 1 digit number.

```
SELECT   num
FROM     GENERATE_SERIES (1, 10000) AS s(num)
order by random()
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT   num
FROM     GENERATE_SERIES (1000, 9999) AS s(num)
order by random()
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this expression to avoid dealing with sub-queries

```
 select floor(1000 + random() * 8999);
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.  Sorting 9000 rows to get one "random" number is ludicrous.

Answer (score 2):

You generate all numbers between 1 and 10000, so 1-999 and 10000 are not 4 digit numbers but in the list:

```
SELECT   num
FROM     GENERATE_SERIES (1000, 9999) AS s(num) // generates 4 digit numbers
order by random()
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will generate value from 1 to 10000

```
select to_char(n, 'FM0000') FROM floor(random()*10000) as x(n);
```